# Delete message only for one user with one field

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a website. Visitors can register. Every user can send messages to another user. There are in/out boxes. I want when a user deletes a message from his box the other user to still have it.

My question is can this be made with only one field in the table?

Why?
**I couldn't think of good solution. Curiousity, friends!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

With one column, the flow would require a `nullable` column.

- `NULL` means both have them.
- If one deletes - `UPDATE` that user's id in the column.
- When the other user deletes it - you can `DELETE` the record.

I strongly advice using a more robust architecture though, less columns doesn't equal better.

@cwallenpoole Has a good example, try it out.

Answer (score 1):

Have a table with columns "message_id", "direction" and "user_id" with a foreign key for the user_id and message_id (possibly use an enum or foreign key for direction too). When the user deletes a message, have it simply delete the entry in that database `where message_id = $message_id and user_id = $user_id and direction = 'out';`

Comment: I suppose it doesn't, but this is how it really should be approached. It means you would be able to store the message once and have it sent to multiple recipients and have them all store an independent "deleted state".